# Conditional html rendering with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, data-binding, itemtemplate

Consider the following code snippet:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Data">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData1") %>
        <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData2") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I need to refactor this so that if ItemData2 is blank, the `<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;` does not render

I am unsure how I can achieve this.

**EDIT:** I tried to add a condition like so:

```
<% if(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData2") != null) { %>
    <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData2") %>
<% } %>
```

It didn't work, and looks really ugly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DataBinder.Eval you can pass your condition like below and this will work for you.

```
<%#( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Item1)==null ?DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Item1"):
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Item2"))%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the `dataBinder.Eval()` statement inside an `asp:literal` control, then add a DataBinding event handler in the CodeBehind, and set `Literal2.Visible = false` based on your condition. Place your `<br/ >`in the second literal.

Note this method maintains separation of concerns such that you do not have C# code returning HTML snippets, but is not "inline".

An example, using a repeater, but all these controls work similarly:

```
   void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
   {

      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
      {

         var dataItem = (YourDataItem)e.Item.DataItem;
         if (null == dataItem.Item2)// this is pseudo code because I don't know what your dataItem looks like 
         {
             ((literal)e.Item.FindControl("Literal2")).Visible = false;
         }
      }
   }
```

Th item template would look like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Data">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData1") %>
        <asp:Literal Runat="server" ID="Literal2">
            <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData2") %>
        </asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Cast the control to `Literal`, or use `Panel` so the panel can contain other controls, if required.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;`, consider wrapping both items in an element that displays as a block, like a `div`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Data">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData1") %></div>
        <div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData2") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If ItemData2 is blank, the div will be blank and not take up any space or cause a newline in the HTML.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMt79/) for examples

Answer (score 1):

i think you can this by define public method in the code behind `.cs` that takes `ItemData2` then check it was empty it return the wanted markup string, if not return empty string

Example::

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Data">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData1") %>        
        CheckEmptyData(Eval("ItemData2").ToString())
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then in code behind:

```
public string CheckEmptyData(string ItemData2)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ItemData2))
        return "";
    else
        return "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;" + ItemData2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of binding, You can add newline and space infront of "ItemData2". ie,

```
if(ItemData2Field.length>0){
    string item2 = ""+
    "  " + ItemData2;}
```

Put this in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jodha's answer, this is how I solved it. Certainly not the most elegant solution, but nothing I can see here appears to be any more elegant.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData2") != null ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData1") + "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=\"color: gray;\">" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData2") + "</span>" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemData1") %></asp:Label>
```